# Completing unimodular vectors  with $3$ entries in $F_2[t]$  to a $3$ by $3$ matrix with determinant equal to $1.$

Tags: gr.group-theory, polynomials

Given $a_1,b_1,c_1$ in $F_2[t]$ with $\gcd(a_1,b_1,c_1)=1$ it is known that there exists an element
$g$ of $SL(3, F_2[t])$  (by explicit construction) such that $g$ has first line
$$
[a_1^2, b_1,c_1],
$$
in particular this works when $a_1^2$ is in the ideal $(b_1,c_1)$ generated by $a_1$ and $b_1$ in $F_2[t].$

Question: It is possible to extend in the above manner the following line $L$ to an element of $SL(3, F_2[t])$

$$
L =[1+a,b,c]
$$
where $a,b,c \in F_2[t]$ with $\gcd(1+a,b,c)=1$ and with
$$
a^2 \in (b,c).
$$

The case when $\gcd(b,c)=1$ is trivial since $1+a = M^2+ t N^2$ and $tN^2 \in (b,c)$ in these case.

The question  (for a general characteristic $2$ ring R) appears in page $14$ of

www.math.psu.edu/oldColloquium/Ravi2.pdf

while the explicit construction described above appears in page $12.$

Comment: How does this relate to what used to be called Serre's Conjecture, which was settled by Quillen and Suslin, and later by Vaserstein and Suslin?

Comment: @OP: You're working over a principal ideal domain, aren't you? Whenever you have $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb F_2[t]^{1\times 3}$ with $gcd(a,b,c)=1$, you will be able to (explicitly) complete this to a matrix in $GL_3(\mathbb F_2[t])$ (which in this case is the same as $SL_3$). Imposing any further conditions seems unnecessary. The slides you link to do this for an arbitrary ring, and only there does the problem become difficult.

Comment: nice observation florian; probably you can post it as an answer ?; what is the explicit matrix on terms of $a,b,c$ ?


Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, suppose $K$ is a field and you have three elements $a,b,c\in K[t]$ with $gcd(a,b,c)=1$.
I will show that the row $(a,b,c)$ can always be extended to a matrix in $SL(3,K[t])$.
Suppose that at least one of $b$ and $c$ is nonzero (otherwise $a\in K$ and extending the row is trivial).

Let $g:=gcd(b,c)$ and choose $x,y\in K[x]$ such that $xb+yc=g$. Since $gcd(a,g)$ must be one, we find $r,s\in K[x]$ such that $ra+sg=1$. Now the following $3\times 3$-matrix has determinant $1$ and extends the row $(a,b,c)$:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}a&b&c\newline -s& \frac{rb}{g} & \frac{rc}{g} \newline 0 & -y & x\\ \end{array}\right]
$$
It is an easy computation that this matrix has determinant one (unless I mistyped something). Note that the occurring fractions lie in $K[x]$, since $g$ divides both $b$ and $c$ by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring, and $(x,y,z)$ a unimodular row.  View this row as a linear map from $R$ to $R^3$.  Then the unimodularity implies that this map splits, so its cokernel (call it $M$) is projective.

Now suppose that $M$ is free, and that free modules over $R$ have well-defined ranks (e.g. if $R$ is commutative).  Then $M$ is isomorphic to $R^2$.  A complementary splitting $R^2\rightarrow R^3$ tells you how to complete your matrix.

In particular, this works whenever all projective $R$-modules are free, which is certainly the case for any PID and in particular for $F_2[t]$.